# residuals input R

Tags: r

I was given raw data on 1960 and 1970 ratio of women number of previous birth who will have another birth. I had to do a 2-way analysis table then a square combining table to obtain the residuals. I did not know how to compute in R, so it was done manually (by row medians and then column medians). This was my residuals for the different groups:

```
P0      P1      P2      P3      P4      P5
0.186   0.122   -0.014  -0.059  -0.017  0.013
-0.004  -0.004  -0.004  0.004   0.042   0.006
-0.174  -0.125  -0.013  0.018   0.048   0.012
0.205   0.176   0.043   -0.043  -0.052  -0.053
0.004   0.004   0.004   -0.004  -0.013  -0.069
-0.040  -0.011  0.009   0.005   0.013   -0.006
```

how do I enter in R, to create a stem and leaf and residual plot. These values are the residuals for the data for 1960 row1-3 and 1970 row 1-3.

Comment: a residual plot against what x-variable?

Answer (score 1):

To get row medians of a matrix `a`:

```
 apply(a,1,median)
```

To get column medians:

```
 apply(a,2,median)
```

To get overall median:

```
 median(a)
```

To combine the resulting row and column effects (say they're in vectors called `roweff` and `coleff`) into a matrix, `outer(roweff,coleff,"+")`

However, the command `medpolish` may also be useful in that it probably does mostly what you need.

To read the data in as a table (i.e. a matrix), use `read.table`, see the help under `?read.table`

To read the data in as a vector, among other things you could `scan` it. See `?scan`

To get a stem and leaf plot, see `?stem`.

As my comment suggests, I can't tell what you want for a residual plot.

This information is covered in numerous documents. To get started, see the manual "An Introduction to R" that comes with R and is also freely available on the internet. There are a heap of beginner R documents to be found as well. One place to start is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html)